# How to create a multipage HMI project in twincat3?

Tags: user-interface, twincat

I’m trying to create a multipage HMI in "Twincat3 Beckhoff".
The problem is when we use to bring to front other keys are useless.
when we use to send to back we have problems such as the other keys don't work correctly. I want to open a separate page.

Comment: Maybe use Frames to switch the pages. I dont know very well what you want.. Multipage including a nabvar to switch the pages?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for are `.content` files. As explained on [InfoSys](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/te2000_tc3_hmi_engineering/3477215755.html&id=):

> ## Creating navigation
>
> 1. Switch to the Solution Explorer.
> 2. Add the desired number of content objects:
>
>    1 Right-click on the TwinCAT HMI project entry or on one of the
>    folders.
>
>    2 Select **Add** and **New Item** and select **Content**.
> 3. Open the view or the content where you wish to add the navigation.
> 4. Add a region and buttons in order to switch between the contents.
> 5. Set the **Target Content** attribute in order to define the start content.
> 6. Add a **SetTargetContent** action to the **.onPressed** event of all buttons and set the corresponding content.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide all the objects you do not want to be displayed by coding on the New Page Call Button.

TcHmiButton::Visibility   =  hidden[enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 0):

The second solution is to make the page we want to call small, but increase the width and height of the page to be coded by coding in the desired button.